# Authentication of Dialogflow API v2 authentication using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, dialogflow-es

I am trying to access my chatbot on Google Dialogflow API version 2 using an AngularJS application.

I have already downloaded a service key, set an environment variable locally, and downloaded google sdk on my system according to the process shown here:
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup

However, on running the code I get the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

I am unable to understand what to do in order to get this working...

// the method type and url variables

```
$scope.method = 'POST';
$scope.endPoint = 'https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/projects/project-name/agent/intents';
$scope.mimeType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';


// the function that mkes the http call
function abc() {
    $http({
        method: $scope.method,
        url: $scope.endPoint,
        contentType: $scope.mimeType,
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({query: message, lang: "en", sessionId: "123"})
    }).then(function success(response) {...}

}
```

I want that this helps authenticate the user and provide access to intents and then respond to the request. But it doesn't happen. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Also, I wonder if this is pushed for production where will the key be uploaded and how will the application point to it?

Thank you!!

Comment: `contentType` and `dataType` are not properties of the $http `config` object. See [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage).

Comment: try using dialogflow node js  for detectIntent, i am working on chat bot also with dialogflow and angular , i was happing some problem to understand dialogflow v2, but when u read the documentation very well on google dialogflow and dialogflow-nodejs, i am sure u gonna be understand and use it very easy

Comment: Hey @poppop thanks! So you're using dialogflow-nodejs now? Do you have your code opensource? Maybe I can use as a reference?

Comment: @JayaRajwani yep i am using it now

Answer (score 0):

Take this as a reference. Hope this might help.

This is my Working Code.

**AngularJS File:**

```
$scope.products = [];
$scope.confirmDelete = false;

// Input TextBox Variables.
$scope.productForm = {
    productId: -1,
    productName: "",
    productAddress: "",
    productOwner: ""
};


// For POST and PUT: Submit Button.
$scope.submitProduct = function () {

    var method = "";
    var url = "";
    if ($scope.productForm.productId == -1) {
        method = "POST";
        url = '/products/addProduct';
    } else {
        method = "PUT";
        url = '/products/updateProduct';
    }

    $http({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: angular.toJson($scope.productForm),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(_success, _error);
};

// Success Function
function _success(response) {
    _refreshProductData();
    _clearFormData();
};

// Error Function
function _error(response) {
    console.log("Error : " + response.statusText + ":" + response.data);
};

// For GET: To Get All Data.
function _refreshProductData(){
    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : '/products/getAllProducts'
    }).then(function success(response){// success
        console.log(response)
        $scope.products = response.data
        console.log($scope.products)
    }, function error(response){// Error
        console.log("Error : " + response.status + ":" + response.data);
    });
}

// Clear Form Data
function _clearFormData() {
    $scope.productForm.productId = -1;
    $scope.productForm.productName = "";
    $scope.productForm.productAddress = "";
    $scope.productForm.productOwner = "";
    ...
    ...
    ...
};
```

**HTML File:**

```
<form ng-submit = "submitProduct()">
    Product Id :<br>
    {{productForm.productId}} <br><br>

    Product Name :<br>
    <input type = "text" ng-model = "productForm.productName"/> <br><br>

    Product Address :<br>
    <input type = "text" ng-model = "productForm.productAddress" /><br><br>

    Product Owner :<br>
    <input type = "text" ng-model = "productForm.productOwner" /><br><br>

    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" /><br><br>
</form>
```